# How can I add 20 weeks to the current system date generated using now()

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a calculated date when record is written.  Datatype is DATE, using mySQL 5.025.  I have tried;

```
date_add(now(), interval 140)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
date_add(now(), interval 20 week)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add